# Display the same DIV over multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, getelementbyid

I'm working on an ecommerce site for a client using Business Catalyst.

On their "Menu" page, they would like to display an "Out of Stock" DIV over the images of all out-of-stock products.

The DIV should be triggered by BC's proprietary content tag, {tag_instock}.
When {tag_instock} is 0, div.nostock should be displayed on all products that are out-of-stock.
At the moment, it only displays over one product that is out-of-stock rather than all products.

HTML:

```
<ul class="product-images">
        <div id="nostock" class="nostock" style="display: none;"><h2>Out of Stock</h2></div>
            <li>img_one</li>
            <li>img_two</li>
            <li>img_three</li>
        </ul>
```

SCRIPT:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var stock = "{tag_instock}";
            if (stock == 0) {
                document.getElementById('nostock').style.display = "block"

            };
        });
```

I'm not quite clear about using jquery vs. javascript. Which would be better suited to this solution?

Please let me know if I need to elaborate.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you also show how the `proprietary content tag` looks like?

Comment: A DIV between a UL and LI is invalid HTML.

Comment: `document.getElementById('nostock')` is only going to get the first element with that ID. BTW, the jQuery call for that is `$('#nostock)'`

Comment: Where is this tag because they look like they are server side?

Comment: The proprietary content tag is {tag_nostock}, this is a server side tag that generates a value from the product information saved in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simulate stock value with data attribute for demo purposes...tell me if this works for you, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/G3uGp/)

```
$(function() {
  $('li').each(function() {
 //  var stock = "{tag_instock}";
     var stock = $(this).data('stock');

     if (stock == 0) {
         $(this).append('<div class="nostock">Out of Stock</div>');
     }
     if (stock > 0) {
         $(this).append('<div class="instock">In Stock '+stock+'</div>');
     }
   });
});
```

I overdo it a little, added instock and instock values aside, Fiddle updated.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the demo, but how do I get it to work using {tag_instock}?

Comment: In what element is `{tag_instock}` inserted? In my demo you see I  added `data-stock` on `<li>` element. In your code where is place for `{tag_instock}`?

Comment: {tag_instock} will output 0 or 1. How do I include this in your code? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should try `<li data-stock="{tag_instock}"><img src="/" alt="Product"/></li>`

Comment: Just look at the source code and tell me where the `{tag_instock}` appears, inside which element...or send a piece of code with `{tag_instock}` value inside.

Answer (score 0):

If the three images are always the same, I would combine them into a single image. If you do that, then you can create a CSS class that overlays the image using a `content` property. By dynamically adding the class to the `div`'s in question, you achieve the affect you want.

The class looks like this:

```
.no-stock-image:after {
    content: url(images/out-of-stock.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -10px;
}
```

Obviously you'll have to adjust the positioning.

Comment: The three product images are all different. Also, the div.nostock should be overlaying a colored background with the text "Out of Stock". I avoided using images for this class. How could I adjust this solution to suit my needs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should use the following HTML:

```
<ul class="product-images">
    <li><span class="nostock" style="display: none;">Out of Stock</span>img_one</li>
    <li><span class="nostock" style="display: none;">Out of Stock</span>img_two</li>
    <li><span class="nostock" style="display: none;">Out of Stock</span>img_three</li>
</ul>
```

Then use CSS like:

```
.no-stock {
    position: absolute;
    top: Xpx;
    left: Xpx;
    width: Xpx;
    height: Xpx
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Adjusting the X's to suit.